# Split Pandas column name by delimiter

Tags: pandas, split

I have a dataframe, with columns headers, which I want to split by a delimiter '__' and use only the first part as the column name.

Eg

start

```
    Red__34343    Green__485838384    Blue__3
0
1
2
3
```

output

```
    Red    Green    Blue
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks @anky_91 worked nicely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.split`:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('__',expand=True).get_level_values(0)
df.columns
#Index(['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'], dtype='object')
```

or as  **@anky_91** suggested

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('__').str[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing in my response and for voting @anky_91 :). I learned `get_level_values` from @WenYoBen

Answer (score 3):

You can try `extract`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(.*)__')[0]
```

output:

```
0  Red  Green  Blue
0    0    NaN   NaN
1    1    NaN   NaN
2    2    NaN   NaN
3    3    NaN   NaN
```